# What does であればこそ mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> **であればこそ**、そうした課題の地平に、私たちにとっての「里」、そして、自然との折り合いかたをたえず模索する契機となりうる新たな《里山》 像という結実が期待されるだろう。

Can someone explain what であればこそ means?

Comment: Please one question per question. であればこそ and なりうる are two different points that have nothing in common.

Comment: It is difficult to believe that someone who understands the phrase 「自然との折り合いかたをたえず模索する契機」 does not know what 「なりうる」 means.

Answer (score 3):

であればこそ = "For this very reason", "Because that is exactly the case", etc.

- であれば: "If/Since that's the case"
- こそ: an intensifier. (≒"very", "exactly").